# Update records once a year, spread evenly throughout year

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

Not sure the best way to describe what I'm trying to do, so bear with me.  I'm working in PHP with a mysql database.

I have a database of 10,000 records.  Suppose I want to update 10000 / 365 each day throughout the year.  Each record gets updated 1x per year, and nicely spread throughout the year.

One easy way to do this is to select all records, then for each, if ID % 365 = $day_of_year, update that record.  I'm not worried about leap year.

Is there a way I can select only the records from the database that I need (around 27), rather than selecting all 10,000 and looping through each?  This is a cron job that I will run in the middle of the night, so maybe this is a moot point.  Still, it bugs me that I have to brute force my way through all 10,000.  Would love to find a more elegant solution by only pulling the tiny fraction needed.

Comment: question: is this by using a PHP script as a normal "shell script" style utility, or are you trying to slip this into something that's triggered based on web requests (in which case, don't do that)

Comment: 10k records doesn't seem like much and if it'll make your coding tighter and more efficient I would go that route.

Comment: in this particular use case, make life easy for yourself and simply  record the "last updated" time in a column for each record, then select and update on "do the oldest ones first". Although it's a pretty small data set and it doesn't sound like there's a reason to not just do all of it at once.

Comment: Thanks for the incredibly quick responses!  This is run nightly via a cron job.  Not triggered by any real-time requests.

Answer (score 3):

Add a column to your table indicating the day of the year the record should be updated.

Then add an event that runs once a year that resets that column values and calculates it new - 10000 records spread on the days of the year.

Then add another event that runs every night updating the records for the day.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response, especially Juergen and Mike Pomax.  Here's the solution.

I added a new column and populated each row with a random value between 0 and 364.  I could have populated it some other way but this was easy and close enough.

Here is my pseudocode:

```
$day_of_year = date('z');
if($day_of_year < 365){ //don't do on Dec 31 of leap year
   $qry = "Select ... WHERE ID = $day_of_year";
   ... //do my thing
}
```

Works great.  Thanks again.